# Documentar e testar métodos de uma ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Existe alguma ferramenta capaz de listar os métodos de uma Web API e que seja possível testar os mesmos?

Já pesquisei aqui no site sobre isso e não achei soluções específicas para uma Web API e que atendessem o que eu preciso.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, existe.

Uma ferramenta bastante usada para o que você está pedindo é o Swagger.

### O que é o Swagger?

O Swagger é um projeto composto por algumas ferramentas que auxiliam o desenvolvedor de APIs REST em algumas tarefas como:

- Modelagem da API
- Geração de documentação (legível) da API
- Geração de códigos do Cliente e do Servidor, com suporte a várias linguagens de programação

### Como configurar?

Há um artigo bem interessante e que explica exatamente o que deve ser feito para configurar o Swagger para a sua Web API.

[ASP.NET Core: documentando uma API com o framework Swagger](https://medium.com/@renato.groffe/asp-net-core-documentando-uma-api-com-o-framework-swagger-c08ffe606043)

Basicamente o que você deve fazer é configurar o Swagger e depois documentar os seus Controllers e as classes de objetos da sua Web API através de comentários explicando o que cada um faz.

Feito isso, o Swagger faz a mágica para você e é possível visualizar e testar seus métodos através de uma página web gerada.

Answer (score -1):

Eu utilizo muito o swagger https://swagger.io/, porém para documentar API's em java e php, encontrei esse artigo http://netcoders.com.br/swagger-documente-seu-asp-net-web-api-rest/ , espero que possa ajudar.